# Using python multiprocess - start a new function on a process immediately after finishing (more jobs than cores)

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have written a function, below, that calls a function (which calls a outside program). I have written it to be limited to the # of cores provided, and it waits for all of the current tasks to finish before assigning more.

I am sure there is a better way - how can I watch processes for finishing and then assign another? I have seen things about starting a server and creating a process daemon, but the documentation isn't very good (or at least I can't figure it out).

```
def parallel_lastz(target, chromosomes, sequence, gene, cores):
    """
    Calls lastz from <target> to <sequence> over each chromosome in <chromosomes>
    Using <cores>, waiting for each thread to finish before continuing.
    Probably could be made better but at least its faster than 1 at a time
    """
    fasta = ">{}\n{}\n".format(gene, sequence)
    alignments = list()
    tmp = list()
    pool = Pool(processes=cores)
    for i in xrange(len(chromosomes)):
        if (i + 1) % p != 0:
            chrom_path = "{}/{}.fasta".format(target, chromosomes[i])
            tmp.append(pool.apply_async(call_lastz, (chrom_path, fasta)))
        else:
            for x in tmp:
                alignments.append(x.get())
            tmp = list()
    return alignments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def worker( chromosome ) :
  chrom_path = "{}/{}.fasta".format(target, chromosome )
  return call_lastz(chrom_path, fasta)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)
  alignments = pool.map( worker, chromosomes )
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```